# Unit test failing. Failed: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HomeComponent -> NgbModal]:

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ng-bootstrap

My home spec is:

```
fdescribe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let service: HomeService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {provide: HomeService, useClass: HomeServiceStub}
      ],
      declarations: [HomeComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    service = TestBed.get(HomeService);
  }));
  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should call get user details from homeService onInit', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'getUserDetails').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(service.getUserDetails).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  it('should dataplan submission page on dataplan submission click ', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'onDataPlanCall').and.callThrough();
    component.dataPlanSubmission();
    expect(service.onDataPlanCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

My component is:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {HomeService} from '../../shared/home/home.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {UploadComponent} from '../upload/upload.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'home',  // <home></home>
  providers: [
  ],
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private _ngbModal: NgbModal) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.homeService.getUserDetails();
  }

  toggleUploadModal() {
    this._ngbModal.open(UploadComponent, {size: 'lg'})
  }

  dataPlanSubmission() {
    this.homeService.onDataPlanCall();
  }
}
```

The error I get when testing is:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) HomeComponent should create FAILED
        Failed: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HomeComponent -> NgbModal]:
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomeComponent -> NgbModal]:
            NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbModal!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the module corresponding to `NgbModal` into your test bed.

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    {provide: HomeService, useClass: HomeServiceStub}
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [NgbModalModule] // I don't know the name
}).compileComponents();
```